# How to declare int variable in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, variables

In JAVA I declared an int variable and need to print it.
my code:

```
public int i=0;
System.out.println(i);
```

Output:1
but I my required output is 01
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

Do this :

```
<%
int var=1;
out.println(var<10 ? "0"+var : var);
%>
```

Or, more typically, isolating a little the algorithm from the presentation :

```
<%
int var=1;
%>
<%= var<10 ? "0"+var : var %>
```

If you want to do more complex number formating, have a look at [DecimaFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of String.format method as well like this:

```
<% 
int i=1;
out.println(String.format("%02d", i));
%>
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, can you please tell me how to  do the same thing with java and System.out.println().

Comment: In Java you can simply do: `System.out.printf( "%02d%n", i );` or `System.out.println( String.format("%02d", i) );`

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try this:

```
<%
   int x = 1;
   out.println("0" + String.valueOf(x));
%>
```

The same in Java:

```
System.out.println("0" + String.valueOf(x));
```